# three.js How to render a simple white dot/point/pixel

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using THREE.WebGLRenderer and I would like to draw a few same-sized white dots at specific positions in 3D space.

Should I use sprites, calculate the 2D screen coordinates and use SpriteMaterial.useScreenCoordinate?

Should I simply recalculate the size of the sprites using the distance of them to the camera?

Can I use SpriteMaterial.scaleByViewport or SpriteMaterial.sizeAttenuation? Is there any documentation for this?

Is there something like GL_POINTS? It would be nice to just define 1 vertex and get a colored pixel at that position. Should I experiment with PointCloud?

Thanks for any hints!

Edit: All points should have the same size on the *screen*.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using .sizeAttenuation and a single-vertex PointCloud works, but it feels a bit… overengineered:

```
var dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0));
var dotMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 1, sizeAttenuation: false } );
var dot = new THREE.Points( dotGeometry, dotMaterial );
scene.add( dot );
```

Comment: if you creating new vector 0,0,0, it is not nesessary to define it, just set new THREE.Vector3()

Comment: the raycaster.intersectObjects(dot.vertices) is not working, is there any way to select a vertex by the mouse?

Comment: For me, this leads to "Uncaught TypeError: THREE.Geometry is not a constructor"

Comment: Since r125, I think they have removed the Geometry for BufferGeometry for free form drawing as is in the example https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Float32BufferAttribute#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial

I will modify the example to suit the question in separate answer

Answer (score 6):

Yet another update: The interface for attribute has changed somewhat:

### For r139

```
const dotGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
dotGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([0,0,0]), 3));
const dotMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ size: 0.1, color: 0xff0000 });
const dot = new THREE.Points(dotGeometry, dotMaterial);
scene.add(dot);
```

Answer (score 5):

### For r125

The excerpt is taken from threejs official [example](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Geometry#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial). After some modification here how made it to work.

```
var dotGeometry = new BufferGeometry();
dotGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', new Float32BufferAttribute( [0,0,0], 3 ) );
var dotMaterial = new PointsMaterial( { size: 0.1, color: 0x00ff00 } );
var dot = new Points( dotGeometry, dotMaterial );
scene.add( dot );
```

Comment: i'm not sure why, but I get this error while attempting to do this.

hand-model-sample.js:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: Float32BufferAttribute is not defined